# compare month in a range of months and get next higher month in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, sorting, listagg

Rephrasing, I have a string in a column having months like '3-6-9-12'. I have to  get the next processing month by comparing the month from the string and extract(month from sysdate).
e.g in may the month is 5 ,So I want 6 as the next month from the string.
 in july the month is 7 ,SO I should get 9 as next month.I want to do it in an inline query if possible.
I was trying with this query to get the next month -

select instr(x,extract(month from sysdate))+1 from 
   (select listagg(to_number(regexp_substr((extract(month from sysdate)||'-3-6-2-12'), '[^-]+', 1 ,level)),'-') within group (order by to_number(regexp_substr((extract(month from sysdate)||'-3-6-2-12'), '[^-]+', 1 ,level)))x from dual
          connect by regexp_substr((extract(month from sysdate)||'-3-6-2-12'), '[^-]+', 1 ,level) is not null order by to_number(x) )

Please help if there is any other better approach to find the next month in sql.

Comment: it's totally unclear.....  (especially this piece:  "in july the month is 7 ,SO I should get 9 as next month by adding +2")....

Comment: But, as you know what your problem is, and the problem is about month 12, then  have a look at this function [MOD](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions088.htm)

Comment: Thanks for prompt response , i will write it again- I have a string having values '3-6-9-12' which are the months . Now Whatever month I am gettingfrom sysdate should compare with this string and givethe next month to me.e.g. for today's date I will get 5 as month(sysdate) so now I should get 6 as the next month from the string. If my current month is july(7) I should get the next month as 9 from string.Hopefully it is clear this time

Comment: no, it's not clear, because after July we have August.......

Comment: Why would you be storing this information in a string?  What happens if the month is 12 but 12 is not in the string?

Comment: @Luuk, OP meant she always want the next quarter end month number. If it is May then next quarter end month is June i.e. 6. If it is july then next quarter end month is September i.e. 9.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai: i know, but i will not guess! Asking a question needs more thinking, before question is asked!

Comment: @henna, How your end result should look alike.

Comment: Or read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348226/find-first-and-last-day-of-the-last-quarter-in-oracle) link.

Comment: @Luuk yeah I always want next quarter from the string  comparing my current sysdate month.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai Hi Ankit ,  I have to get my next processing date depending on the  month present in the string . If its may and my string has 3-6-9-12 as months then  I should get 6 as next month. if the string is like 4 -7- 11 then my next processing month should be 7. Lets not confused with the quarter.  I was using listagg to append and sort the list of numbers to get the position of string then minus it with next number.e.g.for may in 3-6-9-12 , I would first make 3-5-6-9-12 then subtract 6-5 =1 and add this 1 to 5, to get next processing date as june. Ihave listed query below.

Comment: @henna, Rather than finding the answer to your problem, Its too much better to share your problem here. Someone would must have the better solution approach than yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do a mapping of month and quater and then select the quater

```
     with date_mapping as(select 1 month,3 quater from dual union all
                         select 2 month,3 quater from dual union all
                         select 3 month,3 quater from dual union all
                         select 4 month,6 quater from dual union all
                         select 5 month,6 quater from dual union all
                         select 6 month,6 quater from dual union all
                         select 7 month,9 quater from dual union all
                         select 8 month,9 quater from dual union all
                         select 9 month,9 quater from dual union all
                         select 10 month,12 quater from dual union all
                         select 11 month,12 quater from dual union all
                         select 12 month,12 quater from dual),
     data as (select   date '2020-12-01' date1 from dual)
     select ds.quater from data dd ,date_mapping ds
     where extract (month from dd.date1)=ds.month
```

IF your Quater is not fixed you can use the below

```
WITH quaters
 AS (SELECT to_number(Regexp_substr(quaters, '[^-]+', 1, LEVEL)) quater
     FROM   (SELECT ( '1-4-7-10' ) AS quaters
             FROM   dual)
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= Regexp_count(quaters, '[^-]+')),
 min_max_quater
 AS (SELECT Max(quater) max_quater,
            Min(quater) min_quater
     FROM   quaters),
 date_mapping
 AS (SELECT lvl         month,
            Min(quater) quater
     FROM   dual,
            quaters
            cross join (SELECT LEVEL lvl
                        FROM   dual
                        CONNECT BY LEVEL < = 12)
     WHERE  lvl <= quater
     and lvl <> quater
     GROUP  BY lvl
     UNION ALL
     SELECT LEVEL month,
            min_quater
     FROM   min_max_quater
     WHERE  LEVEL > max_quater
     CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 12
     UNION ALL
     SELECT max_quater,
            min_quater
            FROM 
        min_max_quater
     )
  SELECT ds.quater
   FROM   dual dd,
   date_mapping ds
  WHERE  Extract (month FROM sysdate) = ds.month
```

Comment: Good approach but my quarters month are not fixed , they can be 2-5-8-11 also , my simple question is to get the next number comparing to my current month from the string.So in this case in may it should give 8 as the next quarter or number.

Comment: Given a solution for quarters month not fixed

Comment: Or can I get a simple string having my current month also added in the string not in rows but in a single column like if earlier it was 3-6-9-12 I should get my may month to be appended in the a sorted string like 3-5-6-9-12 so  that I can easily get the position of my next month.I have pasted my sql query in the question above

Comment: what if the month is 12 and your string is 1-4-7-10 then the appended string will be 1-4-7-10-12,how will you sort it

Comment: added to_number since it has considering 1-4-7-10 as string check the latest solution

Comment: ,Got your point but while running your second query I am getting 10 as current quarter which should be 5.Also it is giving max_quarter as 7.

Comment: try now added to_number

Comment: yeah its pretty much close to what I want :) But if I give add_months(sysdate,2) i.y. july month .it is giving me 7 as next quarter but I want 10 in that case.

Comment: so if the july month 7 is there which is the quater you should get the next quater ???

Comment: as per the string '1-4-7-10' I should get 10 as next month for july .For may its working fine as next month to may is 7 according to the string given.

Comment: You are welcome ,also check the latest update in UNION ALL
         SELECT max_quater,
                min_quater
                FROM 
            min_max_quater

Comment: ok , I just noticed that I have to fit this inside my existing query (which is having 10 with clauses already) in a single with clause :(.Is it possible to do that ?

Comment: ok i included only necessary with clauses removed one unnecessary one